# How to position text over image?

Tags: html, css

I have image at the top of the page, then some text below it. What I need is roughly first line of text to be on image. What is a best way to do it using CSS 2 (I'm targeting old devices)?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
p.image {
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

p.image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="image"><img src="image.png"/></p>
<h2>Title<br/>
title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since it's 'roughly' how about margin-top: -2em or similar?

Comment: But how exactly? If I simply add margin-top to heading, that would move it down from image. While I need first line of heading to be *on* image (overlapping it a bit).

Comment: Put negative margin on the h2.

Comment: Negative margin on H2 doesn't put it on the image. Instead it pushes image upwards, beyond the viewport borders.

Comment: It doesn’t move the img for me. Can you show us what you did? Is there more code than what you are showing in the question?

Comment: My bad. There is indeed more code and I messed up because of it. Now when I put in a proper place, it does work and it seems like a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to give a negative "margin-top" to the h2 tag. But if your image is smaller then it would be in the center so in that case, you can add "text-align: center;" to the h2 tag as well so that the text goes to the center with the image.

```css
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    p.image {
        text-indent: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p.image img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    h2{
        margin-top: -30px;
        
        /* text-align: center; */
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080.jpg"/>
      <h2 class="heading-1">Title<br/>
      title</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.image {
   text-indent: 0;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
}

.image img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
.heading-1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   margin: 0px;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="image">
<img src="image.png"/>
<h2 class="heading-1">Title<br/>
title</h2>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately that code does not do what I want, i.e. doesn't put text on the image. It also messes up layout, since it makes heading position absolute, while the rest of text is not moving. And also it is not CSS 2 compliant (uses CSS 3 properties).